# How can I see the SQL generated by SQLite.NET PCL in Xamarin Studio?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio, sqlite-net

I researched this and all I can find is a suggestion to turn on `.Trace = true` like this:

```
        db1 = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnection();
        db1.Trace = true;
```

I also tried this:

```
 db2.Trace = true;
 var categories = db2.Query<Category>("SELECT * FROM Category ORDER BY Name").ToList();
 Debug.WriteLine("xxxx");
```

Well I did this and then restarted the application. When I view the Application output I just see information on threads started and the xxxx but don't see any SQL trace information.

What can I try next?

Answer (score 8):

You need to set `Trace` and `Tracer` (action) properties on your `SQLiteConnection` to print queries to output:

```
db.Tracer = new Action<string>(q => Debug.WriteLine(q));
db.Trace = true;
```

Comment: While this works it does not really give much info in case of errors i find.  For example, I have to add try...catch to catch SQLIteException which says just "Constraint".  While I know what Constraint is, I dont know anything else such as where it is happening and why and on which costraint.  I was hopping enabling Tracer to trace will give more info but it gives none other than that it is executing some queries

Answer (score 0):

Look in the `Application Output` window for lines that begin **`Executing`**

Example Output after setting `Trace` to true:

```
Executing: create table if not exists "Valuation"(
"Id" integer primary key autoincrement not null ,
"StockId" integer ,
"Time" datetime ,
"Price" float )
Executing Query: pragma table_info("Valuation")
Executing: create  index if not exists "Valuation_StockId" on "Valuation"("StockId")

Executing: insert  into "Stock"("Symbol") values (?)

Executing Query: select * from "Stock" where ("Symbol" like (? || '%'))
  0: A
```

Ref: https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/38a5ae07c886d6f62cecd8fdeb8910d9b5a77546/src/SQLite.cs

Comment: Thanks but I have been looking there for 3-4 hours :-(  Seriously I need some help and advice.  What I did was to install the nuget package 1.2.0 by Krueger into my app, IOS and Android.  However I see that you reference a SQLite.cs file.  Can you tell me for your applications. What nuget package do you use and does it also require me to put that SQLite.cs file some places? Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The [SQLite PCL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl) uses [Debug.WriteLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline(v=vs.110).aspx) which means that the logs are only included in Debug builds of the PCL.

Remove your nuget reference to the [sqlite.net PCL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl) (leave the native reference), and instead add [SQLite.cs](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/master/src/SQLite.cs) as a class to your project, and execute a debug build, with the Trace flag set, and you'll see the tracing.

I didn't have to do anything special other than include the SQLite.cs file in my Xamarin iOS project for this to work:

```
using (var conn = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection("mydb.sqlite") { Trace = true }) {
    var rows = conn.Table<PodcastMetadata>().Where(row => row.DurationMinutes < 10).Select(row => new { row.Title });
    foreach (var row in rows) {
        Debug.WriteLine(row);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Executing Query: select * from "PodcastMetadata" where ("DurationMinutes" < ?)
  0: 10
```